# the difference between developement and stable compilers?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, dll, gdal

from [here](https://www.gisinternals.com/sdk.php), I want to download GDAL library. I mean I want to download .h, .lib, .dll files. I'm working in visual studio 2010 and using visual C++:

**Solution Configurations : Debug

Solution Platforms : Win32**

In fact I don't understand what's the difference between **Developement** and **stable** libraries?
And which one should I download?
Even I don't know what other information you need to post here?

Answer (score 0):

The "stable" library is one that's been tested so they believe it to be reasonably bug-free.

The "development" library is one they're currently working on. It's probably had some new features added. It may also have had some bugs added, the documentation may be somewhat out of date, etc.

As to which to download: especially at first you typically want the stable version. It has a much better chance of working as documented (and, for that matter, of just plain working).

The development version is *primarily* for one of two situations: either when/if you think you might want to contribute some work to the library itself, or if it includes a new feature that happens to be really crucial to your work, so you're willing to put up with possible shortcomings elsewhere to get that addition.